# WYGWAM 4 is throwing PHP and Fatal errors on 2.10.3

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

Today I updated an old site from 2.2.1 to 2.10.3. I attempted to update some Add-Ons but ran into an issue with Wygwam. I downloaded Wygwam 4 from Devotee. Follow the update instructions but ran into errors. The first one below was easily solved as the add-on didn't have this define properly in the package.

This is how the file looks:

> 'wygwam_module_name' => WYGWAM_NAME,
>
> 'wygwam_module_description' => WYGWAM_DESC,

[image]

I got rid of that error.

Next I went to update the module and came down with this error:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'PT\Wygwam\Helper' not found in /home/xxx/xxx.com/system/expressionengine/third_party/wygwam/upd.wygwam.php on line 27

Any tips on what might be going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum required EE version for Wygwam 4 is EE 3.1.0, which is why you're getting the errors.

If you need to download an EE 2.x compatible version of Wygwam, you can via Devot:ee like so: https://twitter.com/devot_ee/status/695657856733990912

Comment: Legacy version was not available via Devot:ee, however we received a compatible version from P&T. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you getting this compatibility information? Their own [installation instructions](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/installation.html) give a minimum version of EE 2.7 (thought those install instructions seem irrelevant to EE 2.x). Some clearer communication from P&T would be helpful here.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the docs.